# Windows is opening .exe files with another .exe

Tags: windows, windows-10

I wanted to set up Xenia on my computer, which is an emulator that used `.xex` files. While loading the game, I wanted to always open my `.xex` ROM with Xenia, and so I clicked `Open with`, selected xenia and selected "always open with".

However, this process has somehow caused Windows to also run `.exe` files with Xenia. I am now unable to open ANY programs, as they all just open Xenia, even Xenia itself is not working. All programs also now take the icon of Xenia. I have tried deleting the Xenia file and restarting according to another thread, but it does not seem to reset the extension override. `.lnk` files also stopped working for me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is no Default App type for EXE (built into Windows). About the only in place repair (might not work here) is a Windows Repair Install - Keep Everything.

Comment: @John: Repair Install requires running "setup.exe".

Comment: If you have a Windows boot USB, and if System Restore is enabled, you could try to do a System Restore from Boot - [link](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4588-system-restore-windows-10-a.html), to a date before this was done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Explorer which should still work, enable showing file extensions in its settings. Then create a `.bat` file, edit it with `Edit` from the right-click menu and just put `cmd` in it.
Then you can use `reg.exe` to change the value if you have sufficient permissions:

```
reg add HKCR\.exe /ve /t REG_SZ /d exefile
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was able to open a command prompt window by making a `.bat` file, then in the window that asks me "what do you want to open the .exe file with" I choose the said .bat file. The command worked for me.